# Garbage collector in javascript is smart enough to delete empty arrays sprays/dense from memory and considere theme like unexisted objects?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

i'am working on a nested dropdown using typescript, the structure of dropdown it like :

```
const dropdown = [
  {
     id:1,
     name: 'option1',
     .....
     .....
     otherOptions: []
  },
  {
     id:2,
     name: 'option2',
     .....
     .....
     otherOptions: [
    {
       id:1,
       name: 'otherOption1
       .....

    }
   ]
  },
]
```

and if we imagine there is a lot of options in that could have an empty array (otherOptions property), is that could hurt memory or the grabage collector or javascript engine smart enough to handle this problematic.

Comment: Probably best to wait until you have a dropdown with hundreds of thousands of entries in it before worrying about memory.

Comment: "*Garbage collector in javascript is smart enough to delete empty arrays from memory and consider theme like unexisted objects?*" - no, that would not be smart. Objects should be (and are) garbage-collected based on whether they are referenced by anything else, not based on whether they are empty.

Comment: "*that could hurt memory*" - did you experience any "hurt" from this? "*handle this problematic*" - there is nothing problematic here.